# Project Euler's number 3

Tags: python

Can someone explain why this code works with the sample number 13195, but crashes when I use the problem's number

```
num = 13195

def isprime(num):
  for i in range(2,num):
    if num % i == 0:
      ans = i
  return ans

print isprime(isprime(isprime(num)))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `isprime(isprime(isprime(num)))`? Shouldn't it just be one call?

Comment: Can you perhaps quote the assignment. Have you considered input `num=1`: it will return `None`...

Comment: Because it's so inefficient, find another algorithm (ex : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Would be helpful what the program is supposed to do, or what the "problem's number" is. At least add a link, so we don't have to ask google.

Comment: @tobias_k the problem is as follows: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?  https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `range` constructs a list. So the program is trying to contain an enormous list in memory, and it can't. Use `xrange` which will generate the numbers on demand for iteration instead of all at once.

You also need to end the loop early or it will spend forever checking so many numbers. So once you find a divisor, use it to divide the original number and make it smaller and thus manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a default value to `ans`.

When the input number is a prime number, the program never assigns anything to the variable `ans`. So that, when the function tries to return that variable, it is not actually defined.

Comment: This is not the problem OP has been having. The input number is very big and the function doesn't get as far as returning `ans`.

Comment: That's a very good point, true. But `13195` is not big enough to produce that problem.

Comment: That's why he said it works with 13195. The problem number is 600851475143.

Comment: Oh I understand now :) I didn't stop to read the title properly.